# Change the locale/language of apt-get/aptitude

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, localization, language

I have a Debian system on which aptitude produces German messages although I set the default locale to en_US.utf8. Is there a way to change that? I would prefer English messages.

Andre

Answer (score 5):

You can try re-configuring the locales package, which should ask you to set your system locale.

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

You can also run aptitude with a specific locale, for troubleshooting.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 aptitude
```

Comment: You probably mean dpkg-reconfigure, don't you?

Comment: Indeed.  Going to edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a new shell did the trick.